# Missing column in contact import screen

Tags: wordpress, contacts, data-import

I cannot figure this out. The column for mapping a contact import is just missing.  I have disabled all the themes, switching to the basic WP theme, and the backend theme.  I have disabled all the plugins except CiviCRM.  I have made sure my csv file is clean.  In fact, this is the second half of an import that I did in May and that import went on without a hitch.  Any ideas or additional troubleshooting steps would be appreciated.

WP 6.0.2
CiviCRM 5.53.0

Everything else is deactivated.

[image]

Comment: If you view-source or right-click and choose inspect, is the column not even in the html or is it hidden?

Comment: It is NOT in the source code at all.  Looking at the template file, that looks correct, so I'm assuming that it's something outside of CiviCRM, but disabling all the plugins and switching to a WP basic theme doesn't work either.